# Fedora 36, monitor only showing half of the screen

Tags: fedora, gnome, drivers, multi-monitor, nouveau

I'm having a problem after installing Fedora 36.

I keep getting a half white screen while using an external monitor. I'm using my laptop and a monitor, but my monitor is only showing a white screen. When I hover my mouse to the monitor, it starts showing half screen. I dont get the message error anymore but the screen still half blank.

```
My laptop has an Nvidia RTX 2060 and a AMD Ryzen7 3750

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HY3ZX.jpg
```

Comment: https://rpmfusion.org/Howto/NVIDIA

Answer (score 0):

The nouveau drivers are a bit "wonky". If you don't mind using proprietary drivers, you can enable them through the software center (if you're using GNOME); that will almost certainly solve your issue. If you're using Fedora 35/36 with GNOME, these are the steps:

1. Open 'Software Center'.
2. Click on the "hamburger menu" (top right corner, three horizontal lines).
3. Select 'Software Repositories'.
4. Scroll down until you see 'RPM Fusion for Fedora  - Nonfree - NVIDIA Driver' and click to enable it.
5. Close the 'Software Repositories' window and click on 'Updates' on the top bar of the 'Software Center'.
6. Top left corner, click on the update icon (circled arrow) and wait for it to finish.
7. Press on 'Explore' in the top bar and search for 'nvidia' and you will get the available packages.

---

If you are using a different DE or prefer installing the drivers through the CLI, these are the steps and (minimum required) packages you'll need to install:

1. `akmod-nvidia`
2. `kmod-nvidia`
3. `nvidia-modprobe`
4. `xorg-x11-drv-nvidia` (if you plan on using X11 instead of Wayland)

I haven't used Nvidia hardware in years, but I'm *maybe* the first two packages alone install everything you'll need to get up and running.

Good luck and you're welcome to ask or edit your question if this did not work.

**EDIT:** please try the following.
Check if you have secure boot enabled, and if so, you'll have to disable it (if you don't know how to do it, Google your motherboard manufacturer/model). Then:

```
# dnf remove \*nvidia\*
# dnf install -y akmod-nvidia kernel-devel
# akmods --force
# dracut --force
$ shutdown -r
```

Please note that `#` means that the command is supposed to be executed with escalated privileges (i.e. `sudo`) and `$` means *not*.

Comment: hey, thank you for your help, I've did what you told me with the CLI but it still the same, now whenI start fedora it says that the nvidia kernel module is missing, im new to linux and I'm loving it. how can I provide you with more information so you can now more about my problem?

Comment: @rubencxtx I've updated my answer. Please see if this works. I'm happy to hear that you're enjoying it! I was struggling myself in the beginning, coming from Windows, but if you stick with it and don't give up, I can promise you that you'll never want to go back ^_^

Comment: hey man, thank you very much, i’m sorry but it does not worked :( when I start the laptop it says that the nvidia kernel module is missing, and after I did what you’ve told me in the edit my laptop started glitching, but thank you very much, idk if this help but i had fedora 35 and when I upgraded to fedora 36 I had my monitor working well, but when I installed the nvidia drivers it stoped working and every time I started the laptop it said that the nvidia kernel module was missing

Comment: I'm very sorry to hear that it didn't work :( It might be a problem with the drivers themselves... could you try and see if `sudo dnf remove *nvidia* && sudo dnf install akmod-nvidia-470xx` works? Maybe downgrading the driver will sort things out. Also did you check if you had secure boot enabled?

Comment: yup, i have it enable, I did what you've told me again and it doesn't waork eaither :( maybe if I try to download fedora 35 then upgrade to fedora 36, do you think it will work? because when I upgraded to fedora 36 from fedora 35 my monitor was working fine. Again thank you for you help

Comment: HEY MEN! I was able to fix it with this documentation https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/configuring-xorg-as-default-gnome-session/  Again thank you very much for your help I appreciete it, I also wanted to change to linux becuase I've heard that their community is very cool and very helpfull, again thank you very much.